# How to add multiple line as a text on button in java frames

Tags: java, swing, frameworks

I want to add a button with name for example hello world and I want that in the button text hello will appear in top and then on the another line world will appear, so what to change in text of button to get that done

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html in the text of a `JButton`:

```
new JButton("<html>hello<br>world</html>")
```

Comment: I did it before but the button text shows < custom code>

Comment: @HarshPatel Since you haven't posted any code, I can't tell you whats wrong with your code. If you put this at the beginning of your main: `JFrame f = new JFrame(); f.add(new JButton("<html>hello<br>world</html>")); f.setVisible(true); f.pack();` it should spawn a frame with a multiline `JButton` inside

Comment: Actually I am using net beans to generate java frame and I am simply using drag and drop method to add button and use to add text of that by going to the property and then adding text to the text field, in that if I go to custom code option add  the text which you mentioned earlier then it message on button arise.

Comment: @HarshPatel ok listen.. I can't help you if you don't cooperate. I know this is hard, but put yourself into the shoes of people in this forum. You want us to solve a problem, but won't tell us anything about your problem. Please edit your question and provide us with an [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) (Actually click the link and read the page)

Comment: 1) *"You can use html in the text of a JButton:"* You can also use CSS to get around the guesses involved with `<br>`. 2) Note that `[mcve]` in a comment will auto-expand to [mcve].